# Cant get Search box to work after converting it from a Embedded Macro

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a Form that is copied from SLprt to Servicelog, so that users cant damage the Form and it refreshes on opening up.

I did a step by step tutorial on building a embedded macro. The embedded macro worked but i cant get the VBA version to work. (Newbie pulling hair out) There are also 2 Icons that show search and reset (x) that hide and unhide.

```
Private Sub SearchGo_Click()
On Error GoTo SearchGo_Click_Err
    
   If (Eval("[forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox] Is Null Or [forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox]=""""")) Then
        ' Clear Filter when [Searchbox] Empty
        DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", """""", ""
        DoCmd.GoToControl "SearchBox"
        DoCmd.SetProperty "SearchClear", acPropertyVisible, "0"
        DoCmd.SetProperty "SearchGo", acPropertyVisible, "-1"
    End If
    If (Eval("[CurrentProject].[istrusted] And ([forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox] Is Null Or [forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox]="""")")) Then
        [SearchBox].Text = ""
    End If
    If (Eval("[forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox] Is Null Or [forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox] =""""")) Then
        End
    End If
    If (VarType(Me.SearchBox) <> 8) Then
        End
    End If
    DoCmd.SetProperty "SearchGo", acPropertyVisible, "-1"
    If (Eval("([forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox] Is Null Or [forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox]="""") And [forms]![Servicelog]![SearchClear].[Visible]<>0")) Then
        DoCmd.SetProperty "SearchClear", acPropertyVisible, "0"
        End
    End If
    ' Execute the Search as a Filter
    strFilter = Me![SearchBox]
    TempVars.Add "strFilter", "([RegNo] like "" * " & Me![SearchBox] & " * "" )"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", Forms!Serviclog!TempVars!strFilter, ""
    'DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", strFilter, ""
    DoCmd.SetProperty "SearchClear", acPropertyVisible, "-1"
    DoCmd.GoToControl "SearchBox"
    DoCmd.SetProperty "SearchGo", acPropertyVisible, "0"


SearchGo_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

SearchGo_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume SearchGo_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

There are Drop boxes on the page that call various queries. Thus the filter must apply to what is on the form already.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Simplify the code like this: `IF NZ([forms]![Servicelog]![Searchbox]) THEN`

Comment: Agreed. Thanks. This is what happens when you convert the embedded macro to VBA, just way too complicated. Found an easier way. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. You might want to describe your solution as an answer and set it as accepted so helps another one with same question.